# how to prevent gcc compile empty function to same address

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

I add two trace-point in my code, and want to use bpftrace uprobe to trace;

but after compile, the symbol table show these two function has same address:

```
00000000062eada0 t log::tp_fill_aggre_log(unsigned long, unsigned long, long) [clone .isra.1]
00000000062eada0 t log::tp_submit_aggre_log(unsigned long, long, long, long, long) [clone .isra.2]
```

this is my trace-point function definition:

```
__attribute__((noinline))                                                                                                         
static void tp_fill_aggre_log(uint64_t buffer_id, uint64_t log_id, int64_t data_size)                                             
{                                                                                                                                 
  asm("");                                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                 
// can trace:                                                                                                                     
//  buffer's data_size, log_cnt, delay from last_put to freeze                                                                    
__attribute__((noinline))                                                                                                         
static void tp_submit_aggre_log(uint64_t id, int64_t data_size,                                                                   
                                int64_t log_cnt, int64_t last_put_time,                                                           
                                int64_t freeze_time)                                                                              
{                                                                                                                                 
  asm("");                                                                                                                        
}
```

how can i prevent gcc do this optimization ?

Comment: Try `__attribute__((__artificial__))`

Comment: __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) seems works:)